# Change all values in a field in a MS Access database to a constant

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access database with 100 tables, each has a field named "M_ID"
I want all the values in the field named "M_ID" in each table to be set to a constant, for example "1"
how can I do that using VBA?

Comment: `update yourtable set m_id=1`, and change `yourtable` in a loop once you get a list of all the table names.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each table and run an update statement with docmd.ExecuteSQL.  Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Sub ClearAllFields()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fdf As DAO.Field
Set db = CurrentDb

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
        For Each fdf In tdf.Fields
            If fdf.Name = "M_ID" Then DoCmd.RunSQL "update " + tdf.Name + " set M_ID = 1"
        Next
    End If
Next
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```